# Do I have to hook up Xcode 3.2 with my iPhone dev certificate stuff?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uikit

I can't do anything right now, because after updating to Snow Leopard my whole development environment is totally screwed up. Do I also have to run through the painfull process of assigning provisioning certificates and all this annoying stuff once again now? It's long time ago I did that, but I slightly remember I had to set up something in Xcode. If yes, is there a useful guide that shows what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to do anything - your provisioning profiles are all stored in the same place they used to be (~/Library/Mobile Device/Provisioning Profiles).

Make sure you download the latest XCode 3.1 SDK from the developer portal, it includes the final XCode and iPhone SDK set for Snow Leopard.